# .NET Core - Access Windows shared folder from an app running on Linux

Tags: .net-core

I've developed a .NET Core app that runs in Linux (Ubuntu/CentOS). From this app I need to access some Windows shared folder (i.e. `\\WINPC\Share`). When I try something like `new DirectoryInfo("\\WINPC\Share");`, I'm getting a message that directory `/var/share/myapp/\\WINPC\Share` does not exist (and it doesn't, of course). .NET Core obviously concatenates app's current directory path and the path of the Windows shared folder (my app runs in `/var/share/myapp` directory in Linux).

So my question is pretty obvious: how to access Windows shared folder from .NET Core?

Thanks!

Comment: I've never tried this personally, but just curious have you tried mounting the shared folder locally and then given the user that is running the application rights to that folder?  you could even mount the folder in a location like /var/share/myapp/winpc/share

Comment: @Woot - Thanks for trying to help! I've temporary solved this in the exactly the same way. But I still hope that there's a solution without mapping the shared dir because I would like to avoid that additional step in all the servers that should run the app.

Comment: If you are using docker you could build those steps into your container build.